# How to authenticate sign in with Firebase with Python

Tags: python, firebase, authentication, pyrebase

I'm trying to use Firebase to authenticate users with Python. This is my code:

```
import pyrebase
import os
firebaseConfig = { #Redacted for Privacy
              'apiKey': "",
              'authDomain': "",
              'databaseURL': "",
              'projectId': "",
              'storageBucket': "",
              'messagingSenderId': "",
              'appId': "",
              'measurementId': ""}
def login():
   print("Username:")
   username = input(">")
   os.system("cls")
   print("Password:")
   password = input(">")
   os.system("cls")

try:
    print(username+" "password)
    login = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(username, password)
    print("Successfully logged in!")
    # print(auth.get_account_info(login['idToken']))
    # email = auth.get_account_info(login['idToken'])['users'][0]['email']
    # print(email)
except:
    print("Invalid email or password")
#return

print("successfully logged in again")
sleep(4300)
```

It keeps thinking it is an invalid email or password, however, it's not.

What can I do to fix this, and have users successfully get logged in?

Comment: I would suggest removing the `try`/`except` block to see exactly what's the exception being raised

Comment: Please provide additional details such as the error code.

Comment: @Etienne have you properly initialized your firebase auth? I have not seen the initialization on your given code. It should be like this.
`firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)` and `auth = firebase.auth()`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[mre]" and all their linked pages. The question as asked is a good start, but we need to know what errors or debugging information you have. Edit your question, and add that information, entering it as if it'd been there originally, without using "Edited" or "Updated" tags as we can tell what changed and when if we need to know.